# npm run dev generates wrong css code from scss file

Tags: npm, sass, laravel-mix

I have a small project in Laravel, and I'm using `npm run dev` to compile a scss file, but the css file that is generated has an error, now I'll show you.

This is the scss code

```
.nav-link {
    color: $color_light;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.5em;

    :hover {
    color: $color_vLight;
    }
}
```

And this is the css code that is generated after running npm

```
.nav-link {
  color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.nav-link :hover {
  color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}
```

As you can see, the compiling process put a space before :hover, that causes an error in the web page, if I edit the css file manually and remove the space, the web page works fine. Is there a way to fix this? I'm not quite sure about tampering with the package.json or package-lock since I'm not sure about what could be wrong.

Did someone had a similar problem?

Comment: Change `:hover` to `&:hover` in your SCSS code and that should do the trick. See [Sass Ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)

Comment: @TannerDolby OK, I don't know why this is happening but it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `:hover` to `&:hover` the nested selector will compile as expected. In your original code, the `:hover` selector was nested in .nav-link but because it didn't refer directly to the parent selector when nesting, it compiles as two separate selectors e.g. `.nav-link :hover`.

Using the [Sass Ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/) `&` we can perform "chained" nesting. The `&` always refers to the parent selector when nesting. You can think of it as a pointer to the parent selector where `&` refers to `.nav-link` in your example. Therefore, when we do:

```scss
.nav-link {
    &:hover {
        color: #f06;
    }
}
```

It compiles to `.nav-link:hover {}` as the `&` makes the nested :hover definition refer directly to the parent selector `.nav-link`. Below is the updated code:

```scss
.nav-link {
    color: $color_light;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.5em;

    &:hover {
      color: $color_vLight;
    }
}
```